# Django Model Design foreign key relationships

Tags: django, django-models

I'm creating a model for ordering multiple items which I'd like to attach to a Catalog. I can't wrap my head around the correct way to do this. It makes sense to me to have the items foreign key to the Catalog and then the Order with a manytomany relationship with the Catalog. This returns the Catalog object itself in the order, not the Catalog items.

Here is my model:

```
class Article(models.Model):
   catalog = models.ForeignKey(Catalog, related_name='article_products', blank=True, null=True)
   title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   abstract = models.TextField(max_length=1000, blank=True)
   full_text = models.TextField(blank=True)

def __unicode__(self):
    return unicode(self.title)

class Catalog(models.Model):
    pass
    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.id)

class Order(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='who_ordered')
    select = models.ManyToManyField(Catalog, related_name='annuals_ordered', blank=True, null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.user)
```

I've attached an image from the admin: A few more items are attached in this image but it shows the issue. Instead of creating a new Catalog in Order, I'd like to be able to select from the items in Catalog to create a new Order.

[image]

Comment: I'm not quite sure what a Catalog is supposed to represent. And what exactly is wrong with the structure you propose?

Comment: you can access to `catalog items` objects via `catalog` object.

Comment: I've added a screenshot of my issue. I understand how to access the catalog items in the template, but am looking for different functionality when creating an order.

Comment: you msut select catalog for create order. give more explain about `I'd like to be able to select from the items in Catalog to create a new Order`.